# My Derivation of The Mean Value Theorem for Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

Here's what I'm proving:

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$. Then, there exists a $c \in [a,b]$ such that:

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \ dx = f(c)(b-a)$$

---

Proof Attempt:

Let $f$be continuous on $[a,b]$. Then, it has an absolute maximum and absolute minimum on $[a,b]$, denoted respectively by $M$ and $m$. So:

$$\forall x \in [a,b]: m \leq f(x) \leq M$$

Let $X$ be any given partition of $[a,b]$ consisting of $n$ elements and $\lambda$ be the mesh of the partition. Then, we know that:

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \ dx := \lim_{\lambda \to 0} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(k_i) \Delta x_i$$

where $k_i \in [x_{i-1},x_i]$ for each $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. We note also that $\Delta_i = x_i-x_{i-1}$. Now, it follows that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} m \Delta x_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(k_i) \Delta x_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} M \Delta x_i$$

$$\implies m(b-a) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(k_i) \Delta x_i \leq M(b-a)$$

$$\implies m \leq \frac{1}{b-a} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(k_i) \Delta x_i \leq M$$

As $\lambda \to 0$, it follows that:

$$m \leq \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \ dx \leq M$$

We know that continuous functions map intervals to intervals. More specifically, $f[a,b] = [m,M]$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists a $c \in (a,b)$ such that:

$$f(c) = \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \ dx$$

which is precisely what we wanted to establish. $\Box$.

Does the proof above work? If it doesn't, then why? How can I fix it?

Comment: I would have taken the special case integrand is non-negative then say integral is non-decreasing. First fix $a$ and $c$ then would let $b$ increase until the mean value theorem matches.

Comment: Hmm I see what you mean. Is what I have written above correct, though?

Comment: Yes, but it is not complete. as I think.

Comment: @AbhijeetVats: You may use directly the order preserving properties of the integral to get $m(b-a)\leq \int^b_af\leq M(b-a)$. Thenthe intermediate value theorem does the trick. No need for Riemann summations.

Comment: Ah I haven't proved those order preserving properties so I can't use them. That's why I'm stuck using Riemann Sums lol. But it's nice to know that, other than that, my proof works. Thanks so much :D

Comment: Your proof is fine and very direct based on definition of Riemann integral. Good job! +1

Comment: A minor nitpick. Your $c\in[a, b] $. It is not guaranteed via this proof that $c\in(a, b) $.

Comment: Ohh but that isn't really that big of a deal right? Like, do I have to explicitly address that?